# Read ListBox SelectedItem and SELECT from Database where id = value

Tags: c#

So I want to read the selected item from a listbox and SELECT from the database where id = value from listbox and show the full details to message box...but I cant find it I get error on throw can someone please help me how to fix this one...

Code

```
public List<Students> FullDetails(Students student)
        {
            List<Students> studentList = new List<Students>();
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT FROM Students WHERE ID = " + student.Id;

                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();

                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Students s = new Students();
                    s.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"].ToString());
                    s.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                    s.LName = reader["LName"].ToString();
                    s.FName = reader["FName"].ToString();
                    s.MName = reader["MName"].ToString();
                    s.Absences = reader["Absences"].ToString();
                    s.Degrees = reader["Degrees"].ToString();

                    studentList.Add(s);
                }
                return studentList;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Form Code

```
Students s = new Students();
s = search_ls.SelectedItem as Students;
string fd = conn.FullDetails(s).ToString();
MessageBox.Show(fd);
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem  to miss the field list in your select query. I suppose you meant an asterisk between SELECT and FROM:

```
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE ID = ...
```